# Iteration over list in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am not sure how could I reproduce this python code into PySpark, any ideas? It iterate over a list of dicts, than if that idx_key happen again it append and then compare to the next list, I am wondering if an inner join could reproduce it. But I would have a cross result, no?

````
    def get_new_contacts(b2b_master_data, new_potential_contact_data):
       
    master_contact_data = {}

    # Generating a dictionary where key is the idx_key and values are
    # contacts associated with the idx_key


    for record in list(b2b_master_data):
        idx_key = record["idx_key"]
        if idx_key not in master_contact_data:
            master_contact_data[idx_key] = [record]
        else:
            master_contact_data[idx_key].append(record)

    for record in list(new_potential_contact_data):
        idx_key = record["idx_key"]
        if idx_key in master_contact_data:
            potential_matches = master_contact_data[idx_key]
    return potential_matches ```
````

Comment: Could you give an example of b2b_master_data and what is the resulting dataframe you are expecting?

Comment: The schema is really large, both input parameters are dicts with more than 50 fields, on of these is  idx_key. This can be an example 

root
 |-- idx_key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- contact_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- account_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sfdc_contact_id: array (nullable = true)